# Is there a Java library for accelerated vector computations?

Tags: java, vector, cuda, gpgpu, hardware-acceleration

I'm looking for a Java lib that permits to do some fast computations with vector (and maybe matrices too).

By **fast** I mean that it takes advantage of GPU processing and/or SSE instructions. I'm wondering if it can be possible to find something more portable as possible. I recognize that the JVM provides a *thick* abstraction layer of the hardware.

I've come across [JCUDA](http://www.jcuda.de/), but there's a drawback: on a computer without an Nnvidia graphic card it should be run in emulation mode (so I come to believe it will be not efficient as expected). Has anyone already tried it?

Comment: You could take a look at OpenCL.

Comment: +1 You can also find java bindings here: http://www.jocl.org

Comment: whops, just saw your comments.. my answer was basically the same :/

Comment: OpenCL has lot more sense than CUDA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about **[OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/)**? It should provide you a good starting point for this kind of optimized operations.

There exist many bindings for Java, starting from [jocl](http://www.jocl.org/) (but take a loot also at [JavaCL](http://code.google.com/p/javacl/) or [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) that added support from 2.6)

Answer (score 2):

If by fast you mean high speed rather than requiring support for your particular hardware, I'd recommend [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/). Vectors are called [1-d matrices](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/impl/AbstractMatrix1D.html) in this library.

Comment: Does Colt compute vector operations at once or does it cycle through all the elements instead?

Comment: Since it's pure Java, it's probably written as a loop. The exact implementation will then depend on your JVM. Measure its performance to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [UJMP](http://www.ujmp.org/) (wraps most if not all of the high-speed Java matrix libraries) and wait for a decent GPGPU implementation to be written for it (I [started hacking it with JavaCL](http://code.google.com/p/nativelibs4java/source/browse/trunk/libraries/OpenCL/Blas/src/main/java/com/nativelibs4java/opencl/blas/ujmp/) a while ago, but it needs some serious rewrite, maybe using [ScalaCLv2](http://code.google.com/p/scalacl/) that's in the works).